# How to assign return value to __init__ value

Tags: python

I am trying to assign the return values of `getItem` and `getBuyingType` to the `self` variables in the `__init__` method in my Ebay Scraper function. How can I do this? If it's not possible, is there another way to assign the outputs of these two functions to be part of the Ebay Scraper class? Item should be assigned to `self.item` and `buying_type` to `self.buying_type`.

```py
class EbayScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw="
        self.item =
        self.buying_type =
        self.url_seperator = "&_sop=12&rt=nc&LH_"
        self.url_seperator2 = "&_pgn="
        self.page_num = "1"
        self.currentPage = 1

    def getItem(self):
        item = input("Item: ")
        return item

    def getBuyingType(self):
        buying_type = input("Please specify a buying type (Auction or Buy It Now): ")
        buying_type = buying_type.lower()

        if buying_type == "auction":
            return buying_type + "=1"
        elif buying_type == "buy it now":
            return buying_type + "=1"
        else:
            print("Invalid buying type specified.")
            self.getBuyingType()
```

Comment: `self.item = self.getItem()` ?

Comment: Don't call `getBuyingType` recursively when you should just be using a loop instead.

Comment: It's not the job of `EbayScraper` to prompt the user for input; that's the responsibility of whoever is *using* `EbayScraper`. At most, you should define a method that simply takes an argument and assigns that to `self.item`, or just assign to the attribute directly; getters aren't always necessary in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call functions inside `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.item = self.getItem()
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to simply pass arguments to `__init__` to initialize the values. If you want to provide an interactive method for providing those arguments, define a class method.

```
class EbayScraper(object):
    def __init__(self, item, buying_type):
        self.base_url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw="
        self.item = item
        self.buying_type = buying_type
        self.url_seperator = "&_sop=12&rt=nc&LH_"
        self.url_seperator2 = "&_pgn="
        self.page_num = "1"
        self.currentPage = 1

    @classmethod
    def prompt_user(cls):
        item = input("Item")
        while True:
            buying_type = input("Please specify a buying type...").lower()
            if buying_type in ('auction', 'buy it now'):
                break
            print("Invalid buying type specified")

        return cls(item, buying_type + "=1")



e = EbayScraper.prompt_user()
```

Comment: Why define it as a `@classmethod` ? Couldn't the same be accomplished on an instance level without fiddling with the class?

Comment: The main purpose of a class method is to provide an alternate means of constructing an object. The canonical way would be to simply pass arguments to `__init__`, like `EbayScraper("book", "auction")`. This class method simply wraps the code that prompts the user for those values before creating the instance and returning it.

Comment: Inside `prompt_user`, `cls` is just a reference to `EbayScraper` (or possibly a subclass of `EbayScraper`).